# How to show icon with label in a node vis-network graph

Tags: reactjs, visnetwork, react-vis-network

I am using vis-network to show network graph. I trying to show a icon font awesome icon in node. In current graph I am showing label in the node. Now, I want to show a icon as well with the label in node. Following is the icon that I want to show https://fontawesome.com/icons/java?f=brands&s=solid

Here is my code:

```
let nodes = [];
let links = [];
filteredData.forEach((e) => {
  let nodeObj = {};
  nodeObj['id'] = e.Id.name + '|' + empName;
  nodeObj['status'] = e.Status;
  nodeObj['label'] = `${e.Id.name}\nns: ${empName}`;
  nodeObj['ns'] = empName;
  nodeObj['level'] = 1;
  nodeObj['icon'] = {
    face: 'Font Awesome 5 Free',
    code: '\uf15b',
    size: 30,
  },
});
// calculation to create links array
return {
  nodes: nodes,
  links: links,
};
```

I tried to run this sample code but this is also not working. The label is not showing the icon. It is showing just the label.
[image: Currently the node look like this]

How to show the icon with the node label?